# Pipe a report from modind() / lavaan() into a vector

Tags: r, r-lavaan

#### Background

While analysing some data in a SEM model one can list the indicators that are the most influent to the model fit. This is done with the command modind from the lavaan project. I can filter it to show only the first few. The command looks like:

```
head(mod_ind[order(mod_ind$mi, decreasing=TRUE), ], 4)
```

The output would normally look like:

```
               lhs op rhs group mi mi.scaled epc sepc.lv sepc.all
5760         var12  ~   g     1  0         0   0       0        0
7740         var2   ~   g     1  0         0   0       0        0
5562         var35  ~   g     1  0         0   0       0        0
8598         var7   ~   g     1  0         0   0       0        0
```

#### Question

- How to parse/pipe the name of these variables (var12, var2, var35, var7) into a vector of strings?

Comment: Try head(mod_ind[order(mod_ind$mi, decreasing=TRUE), "lhs"], 4)

Answer (score 0):

Rather a simple answer with the help from @chinsoon12:

```
vector<-head(mod_ind[order(mod_ind$mi, decreasing=TRUE), "lhs"], 4)
```

To assert:

```
is.vector(vector)
```